# How to fix 'eslint-disable-next-line react/no-unstable-nested-components'

Tags: react-native, typescript-eslint

I have the following code snippet in my react-native typescript project.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';

const Dropdown = () =>{
  <DropDownPicker
    ArrowDownIconComponent={() => ( // this is the section I getting the error message
      <MaterialCommunityIcons
        name="home-outline"
        size={50}
        color={theme.colors.text}
      />
    )}
  />
}
```

Due to es-lint, it gives the following error message:

Error message:

> Declare this component outside parent component "DropDown" or memoize
> it. If you want to allow component creation in props, set allowAsProps
> option to true.eslintreact/no-unstable-nested-components

Image of the error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfUip.png)

Can I know how to fix the above error, please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just declare the component outside of the parent:

```
const ArrowDownIconComponent = () => (
  <MaterialCommunityIcons
    name="home-outline"
    size={50}
    color={theme.colors.text}
  />
);

const Dropdown = () =>{
  <DropDownPicker
    ArrowDownIconComponent={ArrowDownIconComponent}
  />
}
```

Or, memoize it if `theme` is a state variable of `Dropdown` component:

```
const Dropdown = () =>{

  const theme = useTheme();

  const ArrowDownIconComponent = useCallback(() => (
    <MaterialCommunityIcons
        name="home-outline"
        size={50}
        color={theme.colors.text}
      />
  ), [theme.colors.text])

  return (
    <DropDownPicker
      ArrowDownIconComponent={ArrowDownIconComponent}
    />
  );
}
```

**Explanation**

*Before*

`ArrowDownIconComponent` is redeclared and re-rendered whenever the state is changed

*After*

`ArrowDownIconComponent` is declared only once (or redeclared only when `theme.colors.text` is changed), so it will improve some performance.

Comment: Small clarification I need, what if I need to pass props to that component we created outside (ArrowDownIconComponent)?

Comment: Same rule applies to the props, if it does not depend on a parent state, declare it as a const. If it depends on some parent state, memoize it. @AnnaFletcher

Comment: You pass: const ArrowDownIconComponent = (props) =>...

And inside component: <DropDownPicker
      ArrowDownIconComponent={() => ArrowDownIconComponent(props)}
    />

Comment: Creating nested but memoized components is currently not detected by this rule but should also be avoided. Read here: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unstable-nested-components.md
One way is to have another property on the dropdown called arrowDownIconComponentProps where you can give in the properties. But in some libraries this is not possible, so in that case i also use useMemo

Answer (score 1):

I'm too much of a noob to know why, but `useMemo` didn't work for me. I had to use `useCallback` in my case which looked like

```
const Dropdown = () =>{

  const theme = useTheme();

  const ArrowDownIconComponent = useCallback(() => (
    <MaterialCommunityIcons
        name="home-outline"
        size={50}
        color={theme.colors.text}
      />
  ), [theme.colors.text])

  return (
    <DropDownPicker
      ArrowDownIconComponent={ArrowDownIconComponent}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: This also allows props to be passed in 

Answer (score 0):

Note that memoization does not fix the the problem, it just hides it.
[Official rule page](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unstable-nested-components.md) states:

> Creating nested but memoized components is currently not detected by
> this rule but should also be avoided. If the useCallback or useMemo
> hook has no dependency, you can safely move the component definition
> out of the render function. If the hook does have dependencies, you
> should refactor the code so that you're able to move the component
> definition out of the render function. If you want React to throw away
> the state of the nested component, use a key instead."

```js
function Component() {
  // No ESLint warning but `MemoizedNestedComponent` should be moved outside of `Component`.
  const MemoizedNestedComponent = React.useCallback(() => <div />, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <MemoizedNestedComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In your case it'd be correct to rewrite the component like this:

```js
const ArrowDownIconComponent = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();

  return ( 
    <MaterialCommunityIcons
      name="home-outline"
      size={50}
      color={theme.colors.text} 
    />
  );
}

const Dropdown = () => (
  <DropDownPicker ArrowDownIconComponent={ArrowDownIconComponent} />
);
```